# PHP - gethostbyname() taking 5 seconds to complete

Tags: php, server, vps, shared-hosting

I am using gethostbyname function to get IP address for our domain names.

When its running in apache and also using php in command line its taking 5.0695459842682 seconds for complete result.

```
<?php
    $domain_name = $argv[1];
    $stime = microtime(true);
    $ip =gethostbyname($domain_name);
    $etime = microtime(true);
    $ttime = $etime - $stime;
    echo "Total time for gethostbyname : $ttime\n";
    echo $ip."\n";
?>
```

When I am running above script in php command line by passing google.com as domain, Its returning below result.

Total time for gethostbyname : 5.0695459842682
216.58.203.142

Can anyone please help me to come out and reduce the time to less than 1 second.

Regards,
Vignesh Kumar K

Comment: Could it be that your network is very slow? `gethostbyname` does a nslookup. I changed `$argv[1]` with `example.org.` (trailing dot is needed on some server) and got a runtime of 0.000637s

Comment: This has nothing to do with the code. This is called latency, get used to it in networked environment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that your system is trying connect to dns server using ipv6 but your network is configured not properly to finish this with success? If so, you can try to disable ipv6.

In Debian you could do that just like here: https://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6#How_to_turn_off_IPv6

Comment: Yes! I had a problem with php script execution delay of 10 seconds, caused by dns lookup. I disabled IPv6 by setting **Configure IPv6: Link-local only** in System Preferences → Network  → WiFi → Advanced → TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the internet speed you are using. When I run the code i am getting less than 2 seconds as my internet speed is nearly 90Mbps.

[image]

Hence you cant do anything to optimize the code rather than you need to increase your internet speed.